# GeoServer OS MasterMap WMS topoarea error SLD

Tags: geoserver, wms, sld

I'm getting an error when displaying Ordnance Survey MasterMap data through GeoServer as a WMS in QGIS.

The error is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ServiceExceptionReport version="1.3.0" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ogc http://localhost:8080/geoserver/schemas/wms/1.3.0/exceptions_1_3_0.xsd">   
    <ServiceException>
  java.lang.RuntimeException: org.xml.sax.SAXException: Entity resolution disallowed for SYSTEM org.xml.sax.SAXException: Entity resolution disallowed for SYSTEM Entity resolution disallowed for SYSTEM
    </ServiceException>
</ServiceExceptionReport>
```

Exception report:

```
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" elementFormDefault="qualified" version="1.3.0 2010-02-03">
<!--

      WMS is an OGC Standard.
      Copyright (c) 2004,2010 Open Geospatial Consortium, Inc. All Rights Reserved.
      To obtain additional rights of use, visit http://www.opengeospatial.org/legal/ -->

    <xsd:element name="ServiceExceptionReport">
        <xsd:complexType> 
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="ServiceException" type="ogc:ServiceExceptionType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/> 
            </xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:attribute name="version" type="xsd:string" fixed="1.3.0"/>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
    <xsd:complexType name="ServiceExceptionType">
        <xsd:simpleContent>
            <xsd:extension base="xsd:string">
                <xsd:attribute name="code" type="xsd:string"/> 
                <xsd:attribute name="locator" type="xsd:string"/>
            </xsd:extension> 
        </xsd:simpleContent>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

I'm very new at Geoserver and not sure about the error at all. When researching the error a lot of people get SAXParseException but can't find something similar to what I get.

I think it's something to do with the colour hex in the SLD file I'm using, sample below:

```
 <FeatureTypeStyle>
    <Rule>
      <Name>Unclassified - 1:0 to 1:4,000</Name>
      <ogc:Filter>
        <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          <ogc:PropertyName>style_code</ogc:PropertyName>
          <ogc:Literal>99</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
      </ogc:Filter>
      <MinScaleDenominator>0</MinScaleDenominator>
      <MaxScaleDenominator>4000</MaxScaleDenominator>
      <PolygonSymbolizer>
        <Fill>
          <CssParameter name="fill">#F7F5F0</CssParameter>
        </Fill>
      </PolygonSymbolizer>
    </Rule>
  </FeatureTypeStyle>
```

Comment: the error seems to suggest the string SYSTEM is the problem, can you see if that occurs in your SLD file?

Comment: Just had a look and the word System doesn't appear in the SLD at all.

Comment: I should also say I have an SLD for a different layer from the same provider that works fine.

Comment: Looks like your SLD uses some entity expansion somewhere, can you please share the entire SLD instead of just a snippet?

Comment: I can't share it all in the text above but you can find it here: https://github.com/OrdnanceSurvey/OSMM-Topography-Layer-stylesheets/blob/master/Schema%20version%209/Stylesheets/Geoserver%20stylesheets%20(SLD)/topographicline-backdrop.sld

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer for anyone else using these SLD files.

There were too many  arguments in the xml. Only one is required at the top and bottom of the complete SLD file.

Comment: It's not clear what the solution is, which arguments did you have too many of.